# retrieving data from database via past transaction

Tags: php

I would like to do up a past transaction for my shopping cart(I'm doing a e-commerce website), just trying out from the tutorial.

I compared with the username, if username login is in database, it will show the past record.
Else, it will say no past transaction.

However, 
with my code that I've done up,as shown, I'm able to retrieve my items in the database.
HOWEVER, the heading, "item,package,etcetc" will repeat too for every different items retrieve.
May I know how do I get rid of the heading, which I would only like it to show one time as my heading.

```
   $des = $row_supermarketcart['productdes'];
$pack = $row_supermarketcart['package'];
$price = $row_supermarketcart['itemprice'];
$qty = $row_supermarketcart['qty'];
$ddate = $row_supermarketcart['ddate'];

if ($row_supermarketcart['username'] == $_SESSION['MM_Username'])
{
    echo "<table><tr>";
            echo "<td>items</td>";
        echo "<td>Package</td>";
        echo "<td>Price</td>";
        echo "<td>Quantity</td>";
        echo "<td>Date of Purchase</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>". $des ."</td>";
        echo "<td>". $pack. "</td>";
        echo "<td>$" .$price. "</td>";
        echo "<td>". $qty. "</td>";
        echo "<td>".$ddate."</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
        echo "</table>";
            var_dump($row_supermarketcart);
}
else
{
      echo "There are nothing in your cart"; 
}
?>
```

this is my full code

```
    <?php require_once('Connections/MyDatabase.php'); ?>
    <?php
    //initialize the session
    if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
      session_start();
    }

    // ** Logout the current user. **
    $logoutAction = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?doLogout=true";
    if ((isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) && ($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] != "")){
      $logoutAction .="&". htmlentities($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
    }

    if ((isset($_GET['doLogout'])) &&($_GET['doLogout']=="true")){
      //to fully log out a visitor we need to clear the session varialbles
      $_SESSION['MM_Username'] = NULL;
      $_SESSION['MM_UserGroup'] = NULL;
      $_SESSION['PrevUrl'] = NULL;
      unset($_SESSION['MM_Username']);
      unset($_SESSION['MM_UserGroup']);
      unset($_SESSION['PrevUrl']);

      $logoutGoTo = "login.php";
      if ($logoutGoTo) {
        header("Location: $logoutGoTo");
        exit;
      }
    }
    ?>
    <?php
    if (!function_exists("GetSQLValueString")) {
    function GetSQLValueString($theValue, $theType, $theDefinedValue = "", $theNotDefinedValue = "") 
    {
      if (PHP_VERSION < 6) {
        $theValue = get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($theValue) : $theValue;
      }

      $theValue = function_exists("mysql_real_escape_string") ? mysql_real_escape_string($theValue) : mysql_escape_string($theValue);

      switch ($theType) {
        case "text":
          $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
          break;    
        case "long":
        case "int":
          $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? intval($theValue) : "NULL";
          break;
        case "double":
          $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? doubleval($theValue) : "NULL";
          break;
        case "date":
          $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
          break;
        case "defined":
          $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? $theDefinedValue : $theNotDefinedValue;
          break;
      }
      return $theValue;
    }
    }

    mysql_select_db($database_MyDatabase, $MyDatabase);
    $query_supermarketcart = "SELECT * FROM supermarketcart";
    $supermarketcart = mysql_query($query_supermarketcart, $MyDatabase) or die(mysql_error());
    $row_supermarketcart = mysql_fetch_assoc($supermarketcart);
    $totalRows_supermarketcart = mysql_num_rows($supermarketcart);
    $query_cart = "SELECT * FROM user_data";
    $cart = mysql_query($query_cart, $MyDatabase) or die(mysql_error());
    $row_cart = mysql_fetch_assoc($cart);
    $totalRows_cart = mysql_num_rows($cart);
    ?>


    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Your Past Transaction</title>
    </head>

    <body background="background.jpg">
    <table width="1024" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#EBF4FA">
      <tr>
        <td><img src="logo.png" width="450" height="86" hspace="50"> 
        </td>
        <td>
          <blockquote><h4><?php echo "Welcome,".($_SESSION['MM_Username']) ?></h4> </blockquote>
      <blockquote><img src="cart.png" alt="cart" width="35" border="0" usemap="#Map">
        <a href="feedback.php">Feedback</a>
         <a href="<?php echo $logoutAction ?>">Logout</a>

        </blockquote></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <br>

    <table width="1024" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#EBF4FA">
     <tr>
     <td>

  <?php

do{
$des = $row_supermarketcart['productdes'];
$pack = $row_supermarketcart['package'];
$price = $row_supermarketcart['itemprice'];
$qty = $row_supermarketcart['qty'];
$ddate = $row_supermarketcart['ddate'];


if ($row_supermarketcart['username'] == $_SESSION['MM_Username'])
{
    echo "<table><tr>";
            echo "<td>items</td>";
            echo "<td>Package</td>";
            echo "<td>Price</td>";
            echo "<td>Quantity</td>";
            echo "<td>Date of Purchase</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>". $des ."</td>";
            echo "<td>". $pack. "</td>";
            echo "<td>$" .$price. "</td>";
            echo "<td>". $qty. "</td>";
            echo "<td>".$ddate."</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
            echo "</table>";

}

else
{
      echo "There are nothing in your cart"; 
}

} while ($row_supermarketcart = mysql_fetch_assoc($supermarketcart));
?>




    </td>
    </tr>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: use `var_dump($row_supermarketcart)` to help diagnose the problem. It looks likes what you're expecting to be a string is actually an array.

Comment: array
  'id' => string '97' (length=2)
  'itemid' => string '1' (length=1)
  'productdes' => string 'CADBURY BLOCK MILK CHOCOLATE - DAIRY MILK ' (length=42)
  'package' => string '220g' (length=4)
  'itemprice' => string '5.20' (length=4)
  'qty' => string '2' (length=1)
  'username' => string 'test' (length=4)
  'ddate' => string 'Fri,January 17, 2014, 13:58:51' (length=30)

Comment: @DigitalChris this is what it stated.. 
why is it so?
sorry, im new to php

Comment: "but there is an error shown(red highlighted) when I type this code." - what is the error? that needs to be fixed.

Comment: @DigitalChris I've just change my code above, I've declare the variable and store the items inside the variable. The items is able to be shown up now. However, I'm not able to retrieve all the records from the database. Instead, it only gave me one record.
May I know, how can I retrieve all records, instead of one?
loop it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop over the queries:

```
if ($row_supermarketcart['username'] == $_SESSION['MM_Username'])
{
    echo "<table><tr>";
            echo "<td>items</td>";
            echo "<td>Package</td>";
            echo "<td>Price</td>";
            echo "<td>Quantity</td>";
            echo "<td>Date of Purchase</td>";
            echo "</tr>";

    foreach($row_supermarketcart as $row) {
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['productdes'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['package'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['itemprice'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['qty'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['ddate'] . "</td>";
                echo "</tr>";
    }
            echo "</table>";
}
```

Comment: the [] bracket doesn't work out.I'm using dreamweaver, it was hightlighted RED in those line

Comment: i change it to   echo "<td>".$des. "</td>"; instead. 
However, it repeat all the same items

Comment: I just change my code, do take a look. 
now I wanted to is stop the heading from repeating